# Insert dash after three characters - Google Chrome mobile problem

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to create a script that will automatically add a dash after third character. User can add only one dash to input field. If user use backspace, dash should not be added again.

```
QWE   <- user write three letters
QWE-  <- dash comes automatically
```

This works fine on Chrome desktop (70.0.3538.102). But on Google Chrome mobile (70.0.3538.110) the dash is not removed when user use backspace. Are there any other cross browser alternatives to have the same end-result?

```js
$( document ).ready(function() {

    $('#text').on('keyup', function() {
    
            var key = event.keyCode || event.charCode;
        
            if(key == 8 || key == 46) {
                // do nothing
            }
        
            else {
        
                if((this.value.length == 3)) {
                    $(this).val($(this).val() + "-"); 
                }
        
                if (this.value.replace(/[^-]/g, "").length > 1) {
                    $(this).val($(this).val().slice(0, -1));              
                }            
            }
    
        });
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="text">
```

Comment: Your issue is keyup doesnt work on mobile, youd need to use touchend. Best bet is it detect the platform then initialize the one of two functions

Comment: Also note that keyup will not catch a keypress and hold - you are only slicing off a single hyphen. Press and hold - and you'll see